# What Java library can buffer incoming data in memory and later write to a destination?

Tags: java, buffer, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm looking for a Java Library to help buffer objects in memory before writing them out to a destination.

Example: pull records from a messaging queue and keep them in memory until total records size is equal to 100MB or 15 minutes have passed. Once the threshold is met, perform an operation on these records such as writing them to file OR making API calls to upload data to an AWS S3 bucket.

Such functionality is nearly identical to AWS Firehose (assuming you want to write to an S3 bucket). Unfortunately I'm not able to use AWS and looking for alternatives. It doesn't sound too difficult to implement a custom solution, but I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel if possible.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a Java Library"* triggered me to vote to close because [**questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Andreas that's fair. Should I rephrase the question? Is there a better place to ask it?

Comment: If you looked at the link, you'd find that the text continues: *"... as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it"*. --- Or you could do your own **research**. Your question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Vlad, never heard of such a tool before, at least, a non-proprietary. I guess it's the fastest to implement it on your own, as you said. Even if you find one, it will probably take some time to customize it to your needs.

Comment: Keeping it (solely) in memory is dangerous - what if it crashes before you write to S3 successfully? At least use something that is backed by persistent storage, What message queue are you reading from?If it is Kafka, you don't need to worry - you don't really "consume" the data from the topic - so if your application crashes, you can just read again from the previous offset.